# Change the width of Facebook like button Comment pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook

Is it possible to change the width of Facebook like button Comment pop-up with CSS/JavaScript/jQuery ?

You can change use **[this](http://jsbin.com/yawaxijo/1/edit)** as a template for your [demo](http://jsbin.com/yawaxijo/1/edit)

Or you can use this html for the testing

```
 <div >
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=204724202906269";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


  <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.codeteam.in" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>

  </div>
```

[image]

**Note:Please note that I want to change the width of comment box and not only of Like button**

Comment: did you try using inline css?

Answer (score 1):

Use   `data-width` property.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-width="600" data-href="http://www.codeteam.in" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

Comment: `data-width` attribut only change width of like button and not of comment box below it once we click it

Answer (score 0):

yes u can.
the Facebook like box have an atrribute "data-width" where u say the width to the box.

Comment: `data-width` attribut only change width of like button and not of comment box below it once we click it

Answer (score 0):

There no such attribute in the [Like Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/) by which you can play with the layout of the feed dialog.

But you can anytime, inspect an element of a web page and play with its css using its class. :-)

Comment: Yes I can but the changes are temporary ;) , How to implement my changes?

Comment: What to you mean by `changes are temporary`?

Comment: Inspect element and change the css. ? Css from my page will not apply to the iFrame of facebook.

Comment: It will be, use that class and change the css. Eg: `.facebook-box-class{ height: {new-height} }`, you got it?

Comment: I tried that... but is not working for me... can you please create a simple demo?